# Webgl/Opengl drawElements and uniqueness of vertices

Tags: 3d, webgl

Consider the typical draw call

```
webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, faces); 
webgl.drawElements(webgl.TRIANGLES, nfaces * 3, webgl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Now, let's say for simplicity that I am rendering a cube. If the component of each Vertex are its position px, py, pz and its normal nx, ny, nz, then I have 8 unique vertices.

I can then keep a buffer with these 8 vertices, keep another “faces” buffer with indices to which vertex each face uses, and there you go, shared vertices through an indexed drawElements call. Fine.

When we introduce UV coordinates, though, I don't have 8 unique vertices anymore. I end up with each face requiring exactly three unique vertices.

The faces buffer, then, might as well be [(0,1,2),  (3,4,5),  (6,7,8) … and so on].

So, as vertices carry more information, they become impossible to share. Yet, I need an index buffer in order to be able to call drawElements. An index buffer whose content ends up being nothing but a sequence of 0 … nverts-1 integers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In this case you don't need index buffer. Use drawArrays instead of drawElements.

Answer (score 0):

A cube with positions and normals needs 24 vertices minimum. The shared position on each corner of the cube has a different normal on each face of the cube

As for indices or not, you don't need to have an index buffer. You can call `gl.drawArrays` instead of `gl.drawElements`

As for sharing vertices, cubes have the issue that each face of the cube faces in a different direction and so needs different normals and the texture coordinates are often not shared either for a vertex with the same position. But, other shapes (a sphere, a torus, a human, an animal, a cup, a plate, a bottle, a mountain, a plant) have lots of opportunities to use shared vertices.

Also note that there are [other ways of organizing vertices](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-pulling-vertices.html)